# Eloquent save() not working with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I hope you're having a great week.
I've been meddling with PHP and Silex. MySQL is the db. I am trying to create a post route & controller. I am using Eloquent as an ORM tool here, but it is not working and worse there is no log or a trace about any error. This is quite strange. I know that MySQL assumes that the created_at and updated_at fields exist in the tables. Although they do exist, I cannot get it working. I am open for anything here. I'd appreciate any help in fixing this.

Below you can find the code snippets...

This is the Model class

```
<?php

namespace DemoApp\Models;

class Apple extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{

}
```

And this is the post route in index.php

```
$app->post('/apple', function(Request $request) use($app) {
 $_apple = $request->get('apple');

 $apple = new Apple();
 $apple->body = $_apple;
 $apple->user_id = 1;
 $apple->save();

 return new Response('Apple created.', 200);
});
```

PS: created_at and updated_at fields are present in the model table.
Peace...

Comment: what error are you facing on inserting record?

Comment: you defined a model Called `Apple` and create an object called `Message`?

Comment: Are you sure the message model is being loaded?

Comment: Yes, a get route already works. I don't see any errors, but I traced and saw that the issue was during save()

Comment: @okante I fixed it, sorry it was a copy&paste mistake.

Comment: So it is fixed?
Then close this question as edit your question and put the answer

Comment: have you define apple eg: use App\Apple;

Comment: @Rits I mean I fixed the question. The problem is still there mate.

Comment: @Gupta yes, "use DemoApp\Models\Apple;" statement is placed in index.php